# How to don't allow to type string data in number input (Edge Browser)

Tags: javascript, html, input, microsoft-edge

I have next input

```
<input type="number" name="min" ng-model="vm.item.min" ng-max="vm.item.max" required >
```

But I can type string data here (in Edge Browser). How can i fix it?

Comment: you can use javascript or jquery for your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener("input",function(e){
    e.target.value=parseFloat(e.target.value)||0;
});
```

A js solution. Whenever theres some input, replace the value with the Number representation of it...
http://jsbin.com/xisamadene/edit?output

Change "input" to "change" if you want the replacement to appear when the user leaves the element